# Matrix with real entries question

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is there a $2\times2$ matrix $X$ with real entires such that $X^2 +2X = -I_2$ other than $X=I_2$?

If the answer is yes, can someone explain it to me?

Comment: see Jordan Normal Form. Hmm...if you have not seen that yet, Cayley-Hamilton and a little fiddling.

Comment: This question is almost exactly the same as the one you asked yesterday: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/818628/real-2-times-2-matrix-x-such-that-x2-2x-5i

Answer (score 2):

Write down your $2\times2$ matrix with real entries as:

$$
X=\begin{bmatrix}
a&b\\
c&d
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Calculate, $$X^2+2X=-I\Leftrightarrow\begin{bmatrix}
a^2+2a+bc&b(a+d+2)\\
c(a+d+2)&d^2+2d+bc
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0\\
0&-1
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now, have fun. You will probably find out that, in order to satisfy your equation, matrix $X$ has to be of the form:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-1&b\\
0&-1
\end{bmatrix},\,\begin{bmatrix}
-1&0\\
b&-1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
 for all $b$ real.

Answer (score 0):

First, note that $-I_2$ is solution and not $I_2$.
You are searching for the $2\times 2$ matrix so that $$X^2+2X+I=(X+I)^2=0$$
so $N=X+I$ is nilpotent and its order is two.
Hence all the matrix $$X_1=-I+N_1=-I+\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & a \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$ or $$X_2=-I+N_2=-I+\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ b & 0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0 \\ b & -1\end{pmatrix}$$ for all $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ are answers to your problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can read the answer off of the polynomial, 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0&-1\\
1&-2\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

See my answer to your previous question for more information.